# Find revision line was removed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have some code I'm looking through and in the past 50 commits or so, a function I wrote seems to have mysteriously disappeared. I could do a binary search type algorithm done by my slow human hands, but it'd be nice if there was a way I could do a "future-blame" at a specific revision to see when a line changes in the future.

Is there a good way to find when a line is changed/removed in future revisions given an older revision in SVN or Tortoise SVN?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could do something like this:

```
for rev {$first_rev..$last_rev}
do
    if svn cat -r$rev $file_name | grep -q $function_name
    then
       echo "Function is in revision $rev"
    fi
done
```

You could get fancier and use `svn log $file_name` to get the actual revisions where `$file_name` was changed. It should be pretty fast.

You can also use `svn annotate` (aka `svn blame` and `svn praise`) which shows you each line in a file, when it was changed, and by who. However, if the function was removed from the file, there's no way to get that from `svn annotate`.

Answer (score 0):

[This Python script](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/blameall_py.html) will do what you want, but I have not had much success with the dependencies. You need to run it on Python 2, not Python 3.